# When does Navi say "Try to keep moving"?

Tags: zelda-ocarina-of-time

Whilst looking in a text dump of the game, I saw this line:

> `<Player Name>`...
>
> Try to keep moving!!

I definitely remember Navi saying this but I can't remember the in-game situation when. Anybody know?

Answer (score 3):

This is just Navi's default advice when she doesn't have any useful advice to give. I believe she says it a lot in dungeons, since her usual advice on the overworld is "Here's where to go to advance the plot".